# Error when trying to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, localhost

So I'm trying to connect the database and I get this error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /usr/local/zend/share/UserServer/register.php on line 2

Here's line 2 `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxx","db");`

Not sure where to go on from here.... Also my credentials are 100% correct.

Comment: if the credentials are correct then the db privileges are not.

Comment: And how would I fix that? @Dagon

Comment: Are you connecting from the localhost itself or connecting remotely from another workstation? Are you able to connect to the same db using the mysql workbench?

Comment: I am connecting from the localhost itself. And I am able to. @jpr

Comment: are you working with linux or windows?

Comment: I'm working on Mac @jpr

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect the database with the mysql user root@localhost,check if the user exists in your database:

```
select * from mysql.user where user='root' and host='localhost';
```

There will be a corresponding row if the user root@localhost exists.

Comment: It does exist. How does this solve my problem though?

Comment: Is it on the same place your php programe running with the one mysql server running on?

Comment: Yes it is in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application is not identifying "localhost". Try these few options.
1) Try to connect using the ip 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. 
2) If you want to access via localhost itself, try to update the user table in mysql

```
update mysql.user set host='%' where user='root';
flush privileges;
```

3) Found some tips in this link for PHP specific configurations. I am not a PHP guy and so I do not know how to make this work. I hope you will understand. http://madproject.com/general/connect-to-mysql-using-localhost-instead-of-127-0-0-1-on-a-mac/